# About Regulated and Bounded Variations in Banach Spaces

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, bounded-variation

In the following definitions, we assumed that $(X,\left\|\cdot\right\|)$ is a Banach space.

**Definition 1.** $f:[a,b]\to X$ is of *bounded variation* on $[a,b]$ if 
$$\operatorname{Var}(f;[a,b])=\operatorname{sup}(D)\sum \left\|f(v)-f(u)\right\|<+\infty$$
where the supremum is taken over all divisions $D=\{[u,v]\}$ of $[a,b]$.

**Definition 2.** $f:[a,b]\to X$ is *regulated* if it has one-sided limits at every point of $[a,b]$, i.e. for every $c\in [a,b)$ there is a value $f(c+)\in X$ such that
$$\lim_{t\to c^+}\left\|f(t)-f(c+)\right\|=0$$
and if for every $c\in (a,b]$ there is a value $f(c-)\in X$ such that
$$\lim_{t\to c^-}\left\|f(t)-f(c-)\right\|=0.$$

**Question.** Using the preceding definitions, how do we show that every function of bounded variation is regulated.

I need some help on this and many thanks in advance...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Proceed by contradiction.

Assume for example that 
$f(c^-)$ does not exist for some $c\in (a,b]$. Then $f$ does not satisfies Cauchy's criterion at $c^-$. So one can find some $\varepsilon >0$ and two sequences $(u_n)$, $(v_n)$ such that $u_n<v_n<u_{n+1}<v_{n+1}<c$ for all $n$ and $\lim_n{u_n}=c=\lim_n v_n$ yet $\Vert f(v_n)-v(u_n)\Vert\geq \varepsilon$. For any $N\in\mathbb N$ we then have $\sum_{n=1}^N \Vert f(v_n)-f(u_n)\Vert\geq N\varepsilon$, which can be made arbitrarily large. Since $\{[u_1,v_1], \dots ,[u_N,v_N]\}$ can be "extended" into a division of $[a,b]$ (the intervals are pairwise disjoint), this shows that $f$ does not have bounded variation.

Comment: Also works for maps into complete metric spaces, and under weaker assumption of finite $p$-variation $\sup \sum d(f(x_i),f(x_{i-1}))^p$ for some $p>0$.

Comment: @40 votes, what if our $X$ is a locally convex topological vector space whose topology is determined by a family of all continuous seminorms on $X$. Does it still works?

Comment: @juniven If you make a metric out of those seminorms, use it to define BV, and the space is complete with respect to that metric, then yes.